# Add Query String if not Exist without Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I don't have the `Request`, I only have a url string. Also, the url can either be relative or absolute. And since [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) do not support relative urls, I'll probably have to do it manually, unless there is a trick I'm not aware of. This method will be used in probably more than a thousand lines of code in my project that's why I'd like to do it right.

The following code will break if a relative url is passed:

```
public static string AddQueryStringIfNotExists(string url, string parameter, string value)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
    if (query[parameter] == null)
    {
        query[parameter] = value;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
    }
    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

P.S. I'm fine with doing it manually by checking whether my parameter appears after the first `?` but that would require tackling several edge cases, the thing I'm trying to avoid (like a parameter name contained in another parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that your url is absolute. If it's not convert it to an absolute url.

Then use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to parse the query string and add your parameter if needed.

Convert the UriBuilder back into a Uri.

If the input was an absolute Uri return the entire Uri. If the input was relative then return the relative uri.

```
private static Uri dummy = new Uri("http://dummy/");
public static string AddQueryStringIfNotExists(string url, string parameter, string value)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    var uriBuilder = uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? new UriBuilder(url) : new UriBuilder(new Uri(dummy, url));

    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
    if (query[parameter] == null)
    {
        query[parameter] = value;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
    }
    return uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? uriBuilder.ToString() : dummy.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString())).ToString();
}
```

Example:

```
string s = AddQueryStringIfNotExists("somedirectory/mypage/html?something=1", "somethingelse", "1");
```

Output:

somedirectory/mypage/html?something=1&somethingelse=1

Answer (score 1):

There can be a simple helper which will transform relative URL to absolute:

```
public static string ToAbsoluteUrl(this string url, string domain)
{
    var result = url.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? url : domain + url;
    return result;
}

url = "/page?skip=0";
url = url.ToAbsoluteUrl("https://example.com"); // https://example.com/page?skip=0
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid the absolute url because I'll eventually use the output in `Response.Redirect` which automatically deals with relative URLs. Besides, I'll have to selectively pass the domain every time I have a relative URL which requires a full scan of my project.

Comment: If it comes in relative, then convert it to absolute, append your query and then return the relative part of the url. Otherwise handle it the way you are.